# Why are generic properties not visible?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am very new to Umbraco and did just my first fresh install. Anyway, I am pretty sure I am missing something.

I created a new **document type**, my **MasterPage**. Inside my **MasterPage** I created another node called **About**.

Both my **MasterPage** and my **About** have generic properties.

When I create a new item under **Content** and under my **MasterPage** for **About**, I can only see and set the properties from my **MasterPage**?

Why is that? I understand that my **About** node is inheriting from **MasterPage** and that makes perfectly sense to me, but why does my **About** node don't have the properties I defined only for **About**?

I tried to find the properties, so I tried this to see whether my defined properties exist at least: (They exist in the database though)

```
@Model.Content.HasProperty("myPropertyAlias")
```

But strangely, in none of my content sites this is known?

Thanks for reading this,
I hope somebody can help.

Best regards

Edit for clarification:

First, thank you for your response. My structrue looks like this:

**Document Types:**

```
Document Types
Document Types -> MasterPage
Document Types -> MasterPage -> AnotherDocumentType
```

**Templates**

```
Templates
Templates -> MasterPage
Templates -> MasterPage -> StartPage
Templates -> MasterPage -> AnotherDocumentTypeTemplate
```

**Content**

```
Content
Content -> StartPage
Content -> AnotherDocumentTypeContent
```

The MasterPage has in its Structure option "Allow at root" set to true and in Info by "Allowed templates" both the MasterPage and the AnotherDocumentType template checked.

Now I add to my MasterPage one Generic Property from type of Textstring named PageTitle.

This works as expected. I now can inside my Content Section create one node for the StartPage and the AnotherDocumentType.

Both have the PageTitle and I can set it. Works perfectly.

Now, when I define a Generic Property for AnotherDocumentType, I am not able to set it through the Content Section in AnotherDocumentType.

I hope it is now more clear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify how you have set up your document type structure and your content structure? Maybe post a little tree of how the structures look? It sounds like there might be some confusion on how the DocumentTypes inherit properties from each other.

It sounds like you might be trying to set up the property inheritance in the content tree. The inheritance should be set up in the DocumentType tree on the `Settings` section. In other words, if in the DocumentType tree, you create `MasterPage` and then create a DocumentType under that called `AboutPage`, the `AboutPage` will inherit correctly.

Comment: Can you verify for me that the `AnotherDocumentTypeContent` node in the Content tree is of the `AnotherDocumentType` DocumentType? You can determine the DocumentType of a node by going to it's Properties tab. The `AnotherDocumentType` node has to be of the correct DocumentType to get the properties. Have you tried Umbraco TV http://umbraco.tv? I also highly recommend the Bookshelf plugin. Bookshelf has probably the most comprehensive documentation by the community that you can find. https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/bookshelf

Comment: I think I found my mistake. It seems to work when I put the generic property inside a tab, e.g. "Content" and *not* leave the property as a generic property. Thank you very much for your help and the tip for the Bookshelf plugin. This is brilliant, I love it!